# c2dm returns Application Id as null

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am new to android, i am having issue in implementing push notification.

As stated in a tutorial I read, i registered in c2dm and got Auth token, then registered in UrbanAirShip, with package xxxx,  got app key and secret.

My project team used API 2.1 initially, at that time i got AppId through helium transport, both in device and in emulator.

Then we changed API into 2.2, at that time i again registered in c2dm with another sender id, got Auth token, and also again registered in UrbanAirShip with new account, 
got key and secret.

For first few tries through c2dm transport, i got AppId, then i got only null, both in device and in emulator with errors as showed below,

I don't know what gone wrong, whether change in API level, or multiple sender id registration in c2dm, or multiple registration in UrbanAirShip for same package name or So many uninstalls.
    I have added Manifest file and Application's oncreate method , please guide me to get back AppId.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

     <!-- REQUIRED for C2DM  -->
    <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->
    <permission android:name="xxxx" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="xxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="xx"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:enabled="true" >

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
....
<!-- REQUIRED -->
        <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver">
            <!-- REQUIRED IntentFilter - For Helium and Hybrid -->
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- REQUIRED for C2DM and Hybrid -->
        <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.push.c2dm.C2DMPushReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
          <!-- Receive the actual message -->
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
              <category android:name="xxxx" />
          </intent-filter>
          <!-- Receive the registration id -->
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
              <category android:name="xxxx" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- REQUIRED -->
        <!-- The 'android:process' parameter is optional. Set it to a value starting
            with a colon (:) to make it run in a separate,
            private process -->
        <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService"
                android:process=":com.urbanairship.push.process"/>

        <!-- OPTIONAL, if you want to receive push, push opened and registration completed intents -->
        <receiver android:name="xxx.push_notifications.IntentReceiver" />


        <service android:name="xxx.inapp.BillingService" />

        <receiver android:name="xxx.inapp.BillingReceiver" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: refers to this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises when you run in an emulator. You need to run it in device (and Gmail account should be setup - Else you get an error). Also, it should be 2.2+. Push is only supported on 2.2+ devices. Change the minSDK version to 2.2 and try it in device. It will work.

Comment: hi nithin, Tried in a device having 2.3 api and google account, still same error.

Comment: Can you try restarting the device. It fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. You can run c2dm in the emulator as long as you are using the "Google API" version of an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are using the "google api" version of the SDK you want, and also to have a valid google account which is market enabled. This is a requirement for c2dm.